# NRF24L01 + arduinoNANO

Tags: arduino, radiobutton, atmega

не могу наладить работу приемника и передатчика , буду благодарен и за исправления и за просто направления в которых мне нужно начать читать что бы отладить работу

ArduinoNANO Atmega 328P
На приемнике светодиот подклбчен на D3 через резюк
На передатчике кнопка подтягивает на D2 либо землю через резистор либо 5В

И НАНО и NRF работают с другими скетчами , этот наладить не получается

Спасибо
Transmitter

```
#include <SPI.h>                                               // Подключаем библиотеку для работы с шиной SPI.
#include <nRF24L01.h>                                          // Подключаем файл настроек из библиотеки RF24.
#include <RF24.h>                                              // Подключаем библиотеку для работы с nRF24L01+.
#define PIN_POT A7                                             // Номер пина на Ардуино к которому подключен потенциометр
#define PIN_CE 10
#define PIN_CSN 9
RF24 radio(PIN_CE, PIN_CSN);

int      dips[2] = {0, 1};                                     // Объявляем массив для хранения и передачи данных (до 32 байт включительно).
                                                               //
void setup(){                                                  //
    radio.begin();                                             // Инициируем работу модуля nRF24L01+.
    radio.setChannel(27);                                      // Указываем канал передачи данных (от 0 до 125), 27 - значит передача данных осуществляется на частоте 2,427 ГГц.
    radio.setDataRate(RF24_1MBPS);                             // Указываем скорость передачи данных (RF24_250KBPS, RF24_1MBPS, RF24_2MBPS), RF24_1MBPS - 1Мбит/сек.
    radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MAX);                             // Указываем уровень усиления передатчика (RF24_PA_MIN=-18dBm, RF24_PA_LOW=-12dBm, RF24_PA_HIGH=-6dBm, RF24_PA_MAX=0dBm).
    radio.openWritingPipe(0xAABBCCDD11LL);                     // Открываем трубу с адресом 0xAABBCCDD11 для передачи данных (передатчик может одновременно вещать только по одной трубе).
    pinMode(2, INPUT); // объявляем пин 2 как вход             // Кнопку на вход D2
}                                                              //
                                                               //
void loop(){                                                   //
    if (digitalRead(2) == HIGH)                                // когда на пин 2 поступает высокий сигнал
       {
          radio.write( dips[0] , sizeof(dips) );               // Отправляем данные из массива dips указывая весь размер массива в байтах.
       }
    if (digitalRead(2) == LOW)                                 // когда на пин 2 поступает низкий сигнал
       {
          radio.write( dips[1] , sizeof(dips) );
       }
    delay(50);                                                 
}
```

Receiver

```
#include <SPI.h>                                               // Подключаем библиотеку для работы с шиной SPI.
#include <nRF24L01.h>                                          // Подключаем файл настроек из библиотеки RF24.
#include <RF24.h>                                              // Подключаем библиотеку для работы с nRF24L01+.
#define PIN_POT A7                                             // Номер пина на Ардуино к которому подключен потенциометр
#define PIN_CE 10
#define PIN_CSN 9
RF24 radio(PIN_CE, PIN_CSN);

int      dipsReceieved [1]; 
int      dips[2] = {0 , 1};

void setup(){                                                  //
    radio.begin();                                             // Инициируем работу nRF24L01+.
    radio.setChannel      (27);                                // Указываем канал передачи данных (от 0 до 125), 27 - значит приём данных осуществляется на частоте 2,427 ГГц.
    radio.setDataRate     (RF24_1MBPS);                        // Указываем скорость передачи данных (RF24_250KBPS, RF24_1MBPS, RF24_2MBPS), RF24_1MBPS - 1Мбит/сек.
    radio.setPALevel      (RF24_PA_MAX);                       // Указываем мощность передатчика (RF24_PA_MIN=-18dBm, RF24_PA_LOW=-12dBm, RF24_PA_HIGH=-6dBm, RF24_PA_MAX=0dBm).
    radio.openReadingPipe (1, 0xAABBCCDD11LL);                 // Открываем 1 трубу с адресом 1 передатчика 0xAABBCCDD11, для приема данных.
    radio.startListening  ();                                  // Включаем приемник, начинаем прослушивать открытые трубы.
    pinMode(3, OUTPUT); // объявляем пин 3 как выход
}                                                              //

void loop()
{                                                              //
    if(radio.available())                                      //
          {        
            radio.read( &dipsReceieved, sizeof(dipsReceieved));
            if (dipsReceieved[0] == dips[0])
               {
                digitalWrite(3, LOW); // выключаем светодиод
               }
            else
               {
                digitalWrite(3, HIGH); // зажигаем светодиод
               }        
                                                                          // 
           }                                                              //
}
```

Comment: что именно не работает?

Comment: Не передает сигнал на ресивер , я уже конечно гуглю как написать код на трансмитере подтверждающий отправку , но ситуация сейчас такая что он не работает , при этом светодиод постоянно горит на получателе , если же плату ресетнуть он тухнет , и как только я следаю тригер на ресивере он загарается на постоянку после этого

Comment: тригер на трансмитере , ошибочно написал